# Sharing from Android spotify to my app

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

I'm looking to use the "Send To" feature on the Spotify Android App to show my app in the Sharing dialog.

But, I cant figure out what I must add to my Intent filter so that my app will show up there

This is my current intent filter

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- filter for sending text or images; accepts SEND action and text or image data -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must know what you are sharing, and depends of the `Share to` from `Spotify` you have to add one `mimeType` I thought it would be audio or video, so I used this let me know if it worked.

```
<data android:mimeType="video/*" android:scheme="http" /> 
<data android:mimeType="audio/*" android:scheme="http" />
```

Check out the [MIMEtype list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), this might help you.

Just to know, if you want to do if you are doing a good job try to put this `mimrType`

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```

Comment: According to me it should be `text/plain` . I'm basically sharing the URL of the track. I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `text/*`, or if it's an URL try to `text/html`

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, clear and rebuild your project

Comment: @cjds Solved your question? or shall I still investigating?

Comment: Nope. You can try investigating. I'd be interested in any solution, but I haven't come up with/seen any yet